# check if input is equal to a value in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I check to see if user input is equal to a particular value in of a row in Pandas? The dataframe is from a CSV file.

pyquiz.csv :

```
variables,statements,true or false
f1,f_state1, F
t4, t_state4,T
f3, f_state2, F
f20, f_state20, F
t3, t_state3, T
```

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('pyquiz.csv')     
index = df.index
    index = index.to_list()
    random.shuffle(index)
    
    if user_input == 'quiz':
        for i in index:
            print(df.iloc[i])
            x = input('Enter T or F: ')
            if x == df.'Column_3_value_for_this_row' :# pseudocode
                print("Correct!")
                y = input('\nPress enter to continue: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `df.loc[i,'true or false'].eq(x)`